# JQuery mouseenter, mouseleave function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is these JQuery solution for a `mouseenter/mouseleave` function correct? Even though I know it works, can this be vulnerable in any way?

```
$('.button').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(){
    $('.object').stop().slideToggle(250);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by `vulnerable`?

Comment: you can shorten this to `$('.button').hover(function(){
    $('.object').stop().slideToggle(250);
});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny buggy or even inconsistent

Answer (score 1):

Well, it works, and it seems to be semantically correct. I'd say it's fine.
I'm not sure about what you mean by possible vulnerabilities.

Although, you might want to shorten your code a bit, like so:

```
$('.button').hover(function()
{
    $('.object').stop().slideToggle(250);
});
```